# Configuration of a box app2app ios app

Tags: ios, box-api

I'm trying to integrate the box app2app framework into an ipad app but am struggling with the configuration of the app in the box.com website. Ideally the documentation for their sample app would cover this and I'm sure I could work it out from that; but it does not seem to.

Given that I am first trying to get the sample app working as my own app - I would like to know what I would need to fill in to the "Box - Edit a box application" part of the box website? ( I think Event notifications and/or Service actions but I don't know the syntax of what to include there).

Answer (score 0):

After some emails with box technical support... You create a plist file with the information about your app in it, and email to them. The information to put in the plist is outlined in their sample app documentation.

Once they have processed your plist then your app will be listed in the box app for the file extension you registered.